# Making FireBreath Plugin Transparent

Tags: c++, plugins, firebreath, windowless

I am new to FireBreath Plugin.

I am writing a windowless C++ plugin and I want to make this plugin transparent.

I know how to do it in npapi directly, but not in Firebreath.

Please let me know how to make the Plugin transparent.

Regards,

Techtotie

Comment: How would you do it in NPAPI directly?

Comment: By setting NPPVpluginTransparentBool to true.